# A Complete HTML App source code for Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Where i can get a sample complete html app source code for samsung smart tv app.

like To-Do application..

Answer (score 3):

There is an extremely simple app for accessing Rotten Tomatoes on [github](https://github.com/paynen/RottenTomatoesTV).

Answer (score 2):

The samsung TV SDK has some samples in it grab it from [Their developer site](http://samsungdforum.com/)

Answer (score 2):

you might want to check the [BrightCove sample App](http://opensource.brightcove.com/project/samsung-smart-tv-sample-app)

Comment: No loger available at that link